# How to pass a extra parameter using perform_create of django rest framwork?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django rest frameworks generic views. I am trying to insert request user name in the author field of post.

## Serializers

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    spoter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset= User.objects.all(),
        )

class Meta:
    model = PostModel
    fields = ('author','text')
```

## View

```
class UserRequestMixin(object):
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author = self.request.user.id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author = self.request.user.id)

class PostViewSet(UserRequestMixin,DefaultsMixin,viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = PostModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

## Error

```
 status -> 400
 {
    "author": [
      "This field is required."
     ] 
  }
```

Comment: Please add you models.

Answer (score 1):

you should add a perform_create() to your PostViewSet specifying the name of the field which has to be filled out on save:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = PostModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author = self.request.user)
```

remember your Post model should have an author field

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you should:

- Mark the author field as either `read_only=True` or `required=False`
- Set the author field with [`CreateOnlyDefault`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#createonlydefault)

For example:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    spoter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset= User.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PostModel
        fields = ('author','text')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'author': {
                'read_only': True,
                'default': serializers.CurrentUserDefault(),
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the `author` field from your serializer fields. When calling `serializer.save` you can pass any field, not necessarily the fields of the serializer.

Serializer fields are those included in the `request.data` and author is not such a field.